# Exception occurs on remote server: Table 'db_a185f5_ems.tmpidentity_employee' doesn't exist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I know this question has been asked several times but I have looked into all solutions and none of those solutions answer my problem. The problem I'm facing is appearing on remote server. I am using MVC5, EntityFramework6 and MySQL 5.7 on my local server and solution runs without exception or error on my local server. But when I load my solution to remote server, the problem appears. This is the exception

```
Table 'db_a185f5_ems.tmpidentity_employee' doesn't exist

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Table 'db_a185f5_ems.tmpidentity_employee' doesn't exist

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:    

[MySqlException (0x80004005): Table 'db_a185f5_ems.tmpidentity_employee' doesn't exist]
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket() +306
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId) +67
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId) +17
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force) +110
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult() +772
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +1512
   MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +33
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +12
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c) +9
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +355
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +167
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +12
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues) +234
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update() +139

[UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update() +319
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.<Update>b__2(UpdateTranslator ut) +9
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update(T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction) +120
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update() +77
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__35() +11
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +288
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction) +163
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<SaveChangesInternal>b__27() +22
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +9
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction) +222
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options) +7
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() +114

[DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() +199
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges() +27
   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges() +20
   EMS.Controllers.<CreateEmployee>d__54.MoveNext() in c:\Users\Hira\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\EMS\EMS\Controllers\AdministratorController.cs:401
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9744261
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

And this error occurs in this code in line "ctxt.SaveChanges":

```
public ActionResult CreateEmployee(CreateEmployeeViewModel model)
        {            
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Employee emp = new Employee
                {
                    FirstName = model.FirstName,
                    LastName = model.LastName,
                    Email =model.Email,
                    JoiningDate = model.JoiningDate,                    
                    Username = model.Username,
                    Password = model.Password

                };
                ctxt.Employees.Add(emp);
                ctxt.SaveChanges();

            }
                return View(model);
        }
```

I have checked my tables on remote server. They are all Innodb. and there is no  table with "tmpidentity" as I have not created any with this. I have used code first approach. Remote server is using phpMyAdmin.

This is my DbContext:

```
public class EMSDbContext : DbContext
{

    public static EMSDbContext Create()
    {
        return new EMSDbContext();
    }
    public DbSet<Administrator> Administrators { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();           
      modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ForeignKeyIndexConvention>(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Run `SHOW ENGINES` command first to make sure InnoDB is exist. How you import the required table (copying directly to remote server or using import through SQL query file)? Try copying `ib_logfile*` and `ibdata` (all `ib*` files in MySQL root data directory) files too.

Comment: Show Engine shows the InnoDB as engine. I have imported from mysql workbench after creating a dump file and transfer it via ftp. Remote server is using phpMyAdmin. I do not have access to the server's root directory on the hosting domain. How i add these files. please help.

Comment: In case the production server OS is Unix family and you have used `mysqldump` to import tables, ensure all identifiers declared on EF are following case-sensitivity rules on production server. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html for details.

Answer (score 1):

I know this replay is too late to you. It is for others.
I got the same issue today. I also didn't get any idea about this error. After that I understood auto generated guid is maintain in mysql with a trigger. Trigger generated by MySql connector. I missed it. I copy paste that trigger from another table. My Issue is fixed.

details is there https://musthaan.com/2017/06/13/getting-error-on-add-new-table-conjero-tmpidentity_project_consultant_order-doesnt-exist-on-mysql-codefirst-with-ef/

Comment: Thank for the response. I hope this will be helpful for others (y)

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

I have changed the primary key from Guid to int, and i don't know how but it worked. 
This was my model before

```
 public class Employee
{       
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }      
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime JoiningDate { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }    
}
```

And I just changed the PK to int type.

```
 public class Employee
{       
    [Key]
    [Required]       
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }      
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime JoiningDate { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }    
}
```

Can anyone explain this. From this it seems that I have to change the pk type all over the code. Does Guid type has to do anything with remote server?

PS: I'm using the Windows based platform on remote server.